# Some Network URL is getting aborted for IE browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are some Network URL getting aborted for IE browsers alone.Here is the code for load the URL in network.Please tell me how to rectify the problem?

```
$(obj_KLImages).each(function(){
$(this).attr('src', '');
$(this).attr('src', ishttpHead($(this).attr('longdesc')));
});
```

Comment: Give more details please. I don't understand what you're trying to do with this code.

Comment: Here these code will load some image URLs in Network.For IE browser alone, that URL result state is coming like aborted.I want that url must be load properly without any interruption. For Eg: www.google.com this URL only getting aborted in IE Browsers.

Comment: URL                   Method   Result     Type   Received  
    http://www.google.com/ GET     (Aborted)   0 B    0.56 s

Comment: edit your question to add these details and others. Don't be afraid to explain clearly the goal, how you think you can do it, what's the problem, eso. A 5-lines post is not considered really complete by IT guys...

Comment: Actually the issue is, the connection URL is getting aborted state in Network tab.(For Example: WWW.Google.COM). The above code only will load the URL in network tab. The issue is IE only, but chrome and Firefox working fine.